# Multivariate normal distribution in Matlab. Peak shaped?

Tags: matlab, probability, normal-distribution

I'm trying to calculate a bivariate normal distribution in matlab(with mvnpdf), but the pdf I obtain has a strange shape with several peaks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmiFZ.png

This is the code I use:

```
s=[3,1]';
C_ee = [0.0473   -0.1446;
       -0.1446    0.4440]

x1 = -5:.2:5; x2 = -5:.2:5;
[X1,X2] = meshgrid(x1,x2);
F = mvnpdf([X1(:) X2(:)],s',C_ee);
F = reshape(F,length(x2),length(x1));
figure(1);
surf(x1,x2,F);
caxis([min(F(:))-.5*range(F(:)),max(F(:))]);
axis([-5 5 -5 5 0 5])
xlabel('Re'); ylabel('Im'); zlabel('Probability Density');
```

I've noticed, that when I increase the value of C_ee (sigma matrix), for instance C_ee+0.05 the shape starts to look normal.

I notice that this matrix is close to not being positive definite... but it still is.

Could anyone explain this behaviour?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is **too coarse sampling** in the `x1` and `x2` axes. Try changing your sampling step `.2` into `.002` for example. Also, the pdf is concentrated on a small area, specially in the `x1` direction. So you could "zoom" a little changing the interval endpoints. For example, use

```
x1 = 2:.002:4; x2 = -3:.002:4;
```

In the figures below I'm using

```
imagesc(x1, x2, F)
```

instead of `surf(x1,x2,F)` to get a better representation. First figure is with your original sampling, and second with `x1` and `x2` as in my line above. Comparing both figures, the sampling issue is evident. Note that the axis scales are different.

[image: Original]

[image: Modified]